# Exclude href from HTML <BASE> redirection

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an existing application which is essentially a very large .js file inside a thin HTML page.  The script references a large number of files in an `assets/` directory via relative URIs.

I want to run the app on a number of test servers without having to either A) copy thousands of asset files to each test server, or B) rewrite every asset reference in the JS to use an absolute URL.

The solution I came up with was to copy only the .js and .html files to the test server, and to use the HTML `<BASE>` tag to redirect the assets to the production server.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>MyApp</TITLE>
<BASE href="https://www.example.com/production-app.html" />
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<SCRIPT src="./app.js"></SCRIPT>
</BODY></HTML>
```

The only problem I have now is that the `<BASE>` is also redirecting the `<SCRIPT>` tag to load the production copy of `app.js`, instead of my test copy.  *Is there a way to exclude this one reference from the `<BASE>` and force it to look in the same directory as the html file?*

I found a workaround by using an absolute URL to the test server in the script tag, but this requires a separate copy of the HTML on each test server, and seems clunky.

Comment: One other thing you could do... mount the prod `assets/` dir on the test machine(s); create a symlink if you can't mount where you want.  But ***I*** would have all those assets as part of my project and _deploy_ them to both test and prod servers.  Being able to deploy from scratch is a _feature_ of good source control (and build automation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot exclude links, as this is the intended behaviour for the `base` tag, you would actually need to specify a full absolute URL to over ride the base href.